# Why CDN are disabled in local my chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cdn

I often my test javascript snippet code using Chrome developer tools and I came up with debugging of inputing URL search bar: data:text/html,  and running code chrome snippets.

This way works in Vue.js's CDN though some strange error message occurs.But,jQuery via CDN doesn't load like photo.

I want to know reason why these happens.Any tips would greatly help.
So,please give me advise if something occurs  to you however it is little.[image]

**Edit:**

I added photo load jquery snippets and it works in Google Home.
My html environment is reproducible only inputting your chrome browser's url_bar,`data:text/html, <html contenteditable>` which makes your browser html-editor and it can run javascript using script tag.

[image]

Comment: Where is the code that's responsible for loading jQuery?

Comment: post your html and js

Comment: So are you running off the file protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your code is loading jQuery without a protocal ( http://, https:// ). The code you have loads the resource based on what your page uses for maximum security. Your page doesn't have use http:// or https:// unless it is online.

Change it to http:// and it will load, but if you're using SSL and your page is loading through https:// when online, then change it back to :// when it's online.

Comment: sure,I actually tried adding https:// prefix before asking because I suspected  browser translated url with file:// added.When I did just before, I had same error.But,now I can load jQuery with  https:// prefix explicitly added. It seems that my mistake to input url or network or security policy setting or  CDN's trouble and so on.In anyway I can execute cdn's code while the reason ambiguous.Thanks for your answering.